# bulma level inside box overflowing

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am having trouble trying to have a responsive grid of 3 boxes with some aligned content inside using the library Bulma. I would like to make it work still maintaining the level inside a box if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the result I expect:

[image]

But when decreasing the width, it breaks:

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
<div className="columns sub">
          {this.props.options.map(option => (
            <div className="column is-one-third" key={option.id}>
              <div
                name={option.id}
                className={
                  `box ` +
                  (this.props.optionToBeChosen === option.id
                    ? "box-is-active"
                    : "")
                }
                onClick={() => this.props.onClick(option.id)}
              >
                <div className="level is-mobile">
                  <div className="level-item level-left">
                    <div>
                      <p className="box-text-title">{option.title}</p>
                      <p className="box-text-small">{option.description}</p>
                      <p className="box-text-small">{option.description2}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="level-item level-right has-text-right">
                    <div>
                      <p className="box-text-demo">{option.cta}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Bulma levels are explicitly told not to shrink

```
.level-left, .level-right {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

You'll have to override that to get the levels to not break out of the `.box` elements.

Rather than overriding ALL level items, I suggest you add a custom class to those levels that you want to be able to shrink.

Something like

```
<div class="level is-mobile level-is-shrinkable">
   Level items here...
</div>

<style>
    .level-is-shrinkable .level-left,
    .level-is-shrinkable .level-right {
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: going to test it now

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to add a third styling condition for centered `level-item` elements:

```
.level-is-shrinkable .level-left,
.level-is-shrinkable .level-item,
.level-is-shrinkable .level-right {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Many thanks to just-a-web-designer for his|her answer.